# why bash script runs without .sh?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a bash script which by mistake has been named with .py (e.g. test.py)
This script runs without any problem. (./test.py)
In case it might be useful, here is the information from ls -l command: -rwxr-xr-x.

My question is why the script (test.py) executes with out being named correctly as (test.sh)
Might it cause a problem?

The script content looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


export SINGULARITYENV_LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export SINGULARITYENV_LANG=C.UTF-8

CONTAINER=/mnt/pynet-pytorch-181.sif

# Pretrain
DATA=/mnt/Dataset/
EXPERIMENT_NAME=./2022_12_16/


srun -c 4 --gres=gpu:a6000:1 --mem=32G singularity exec -B /mnt:/mnt/ \
--nv $CONTAINER \
python train.py --dataroot $DATA \
               --device "cuda" \
               --pre_denoising False \
               --experiment_name $EXPERIMENT_NAME \
               --epochs 200
```

I tried running another bash script with the same naming problem *.py
again it executes without a problem. I don't understand why it works though.

Comment: It works because of `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of a script. It is called shebang: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unixes don't care about extensions.
If the file is executable + readable (for binaries, it doesn't even need to be readable) and starts with `#!`, the executable that follows it is invoked with the name of the script as its argument.

In your case, the OS will execute `/bin/bash path_to_your_script YourArguments...`. And `bash` doesn't care about extensions either.

Note: for better portability, you might want to do `#!/urs/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash` as not all systems have bash at `/bin/bash` (env will look up the actual path using the $PATH environment variable). Or just use the POSIX shell at `/bin/sh`.
As [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) suggests, you might also want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) especially if you want mess with custom shebang lines because shebang lines are not scripts themselves and are limited in length (like 128 or 256 bytes) and argument passing: namely they only support argument.

Comment: See also the Wikipedia entry for [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` doesn't really have anything to do with portability. 1) The POSIX standard doesn't require that it be present, and 2) if it is present, it isn't required be installed under `/usr/bin`, and 3) it just shifts the responsibility of locating the appropriate interpreter from the *installer* (who should be responsible for setting the correct shebang, not the author) to the end user (who has to know which interpreter is necessary and ensure it can be found via path lookup).

Comment: Plus, `/usr/bin/env bash` doesn't do any good if the user's `PATH` doesn't find the right *version* of `bash` required by the script.

Comment: @chepner It's most portable to just use `/bin/sh`, but if you need bash,  `/usr/bin/env bash` has helped me the most so far. (Tried having scripts that ran at Linux, Cygwin, FreeBSD and MacOS).

Comment: Likely, the only users seeing a positive difference are the macOS users that have installed a newer version of `bash` along side the ancient `/bin/bash` that Apple still ships. (And most of them are likely knowledgable enough to edit the shebang or simply disregard the shebang in favor of `bash ...`.) How portable does your script become if you start using features specific to `bash` 5 or higher? As far as I know, most OS distributions still ship `bash` 4.4 (or even earlier), despite `bash` 5 having been released nearly 4 years ago.